# OSError: libcudart.so.10.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: google-colaboratory

For some reason, I am getting this error on Colab, even if I don't use GPU... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! The error message is as following:

OSError: libcudart.so.10.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 8):

The reason is a mismatch of CUDA versions. I ran into this issue because the preinstalled version of pytorch did match the default version which I installed using `%pip install torchaudio` (CUDA 10.2). `print(torch.__version__)` gives 1.10.0+cu111 (CUDA 11.1).

So I reinstalled pytorch, torchaudio and torch vision with the command stated on the [pytorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

```
%pip install torch==1.10.0+cu113 torchvision==0.11.1+cu113 torchaudio==0.10.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

After restarting the environment, it should work.

This method uninstalls pytorch and reinstalls another version, it would be faster to just install the matching version of pytorch, in my case:

```
%pip install -q torchaudio==0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
```

I don't know if it would be better to install the cu113 variant.

Comment: running the command: 

 
`pip install torch==1.10.0+cu113 torchvision==0.11.1+cu113 torchaudio==0.10.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html`

exists with:


`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.0+cu113`

Comment: I got the same error message as @LivneRosenblum

Comment: Did you try one of the commands in on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/?
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio` or `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116`

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would suggest to check the error logs to find out the python package that causes the error. In my case, it was generated in torch-cluster and it simply resolved by downgrading torch-cluster to 1.5.9 (recent version is 1.6.0 which is release just couple of weeks back and was installed by default)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by replacing the version of `torchaudio` installed by `pip` with the one from conda.

```
pip uninstall torchaudio
conda install torchaudio -c pytorch
```

Notice the message of conda, it installs the version with bundled CUDA lib:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

torchaudio         pytorch/linux-64::torchaudio-0.11.0-py38_cu113
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running below command

```
pip install xformers==v0.0.22
```

I had the same issue on Google Colab Research notebook, after I run the above command and restart the notebook my issue was resolved.

Thank to **bhupendrathore** for this. You can see more details on
https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/1369

Comment: I issued the command above and it's like running forever. Wasting much time.